# CONFIGURATION_AppStore. What is this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

In an app code I'm working on, I've found some code referring to AppStore/Betatest macros, for example:

```
#if defined(CONFIGURATION_AppStore)
    [Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"XXXX"];
    [Crittercism setUsername:[UIDevice deviceIdentifier]];
#elif defined(CONFIGURATION_Betatest)
    [Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"YYYY"];
    [Crittercism setUsername:[UIDevice deviceIdentifier]];
#endif
```

The problem is that I can't find the definition for `CONFIGURATION_AppStore` and `CONFIGURATION_Betatest`. Looking on the Internet, BTW, their usage looks pretty common.

Can you provide more details or where can I check for their definition? Are they part of the iOS frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these are preprocessor macros. You can find them in the build settings of your project or target, under Apple LLVM 6.1 Preprocessing -> Preprocessor macros.

You can also define these with

```
#define CONFIGURATION_AppStore 1
```

somewhere in your code, but this is not likely for these names.

Comment: Thanks, I've found them!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't do anything special, your project will have two configuration: DEBUG and RELEASE. However, you can create all kinds of configurations yourself.

CONFIGURATION_AppStore is probably defined in your build settings. Have a look there.